# PowerApps, Using Gallery to Display Collection + an Additional Variable

Tags: excel, office365, gallery, mobile-application, powerapps

I am very new to PowerApps and I'm working on developing an App which will display the lunch selections for our cafeteria. There are a static number of items that are served daily (i.e hot dogs, sandwiches, salads, etc.) and then a lunch special everyday. The static items are stored as a collection with the name `Static_Lunch`. This collection is generated on the welcome page through a ClearCollect on the OnStart:

```
ClearCollect(Static_Lunch, {Food:"Sandwhich"}, {Food:"Yogurt"}, {Food:"Salad"}, {Food:"Hot Dogs"}, {Food:"Baked Potato"},{Food: "Apple"}, {Food: "Fee"},{Food:"Fi"}, {Food:"Fo"}, {Food:"Fum"})
```

Then there is the daily lunch special which is stored in an excel file that will be updated weekly by the Cafeteria. This is an Entity in PowerApps called `Test_Data` which is an excel sheet with two columns for date and the respective special.

I am trying to display a screen that has the lunch special on top and then all of the static items below all in one Gallery (doesn't necessarily need to be a gallery, just something with a continuous scroll). I am finding the lunch special for that day using:

```
Filter(Test_Data, Text( Now(), "mm/dd/yyyy" )))
```

What would be the best method for displaying both the lunch special and the static food in one continuous scroll-able screen?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add the Filter() result as the first parameter to the ClearCollect() call. So the special that matches your Filter will be added to Static_Lunch first, then the rest of the items will be added.

Comment: Hi Allen, thank you for the response! I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the format of how this code would look. Since the `Filter()` function requires a source and a logical input, where after the open parenthesis of the Filter function would the rest of the `ClearCollect()` code go?